# Does ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission include ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissons

Tags: java, android, permissions

Good day i was wondering if the user grants an application access to the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission if that application would also automatically have access to the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION API methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [LocationManager API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager) and in an [older version](http://175.24.133.176/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) of the guide:

> If you are using both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER, then you need
> to request only the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, because it
> includes permission for both providers. (Permission for
> ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION includes permission only for NETWORK_PROVIDER.)

In short: yes, you are allowing to ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION if you've already defined ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

Comment: Would this allow me to also access other API calls which are normally behind the coarse permission or does it only include providers

Comment: Yes, if you request ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, you API calls have access also to coarse permissions.